# How bucket location change in hashmap is adopted by the application code which is already using that hashmap?

Tags: java, hash, collections, hashmap, hashtable

In Hashmap , we know rehashing will take place when loadfactor is reached. During rehashing the objects in a bucket can be relocated to new bucket. How this location change is adopted by the application which is already using that hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

The application doesn't see any change.  From the application's perspective, it just called `put` in the `HashMap`, and it took a while.  When `put` returns, the table has been rebuilt, but it's still the same `HashMap`, it just changed the values of its internal variables (i.e. the reference to the hash table).

Comment: But get() will have some impact ..right?. There is a change in generated hash ..right?